# Dudas sobre mi primer programa

Tags: java

Soy nuevo, tengo conocimientos básicos de C++, pero estoy aprendiendo a través de videos y así.
¿Por qué se crean como clases a los programas?¿Qué es el `args`?¿Qué es el método main?
En un video vi algo sobre el metodo main que dice asi:

```
public class braian{
  public static void main(String args[]){ //a esto le llaman metodo main
   System.out.println("Hola mundo"); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas libros, pdfs de java ahi siempre cuando inician explican conceptos basicos no dejes que tu aprendizaje dependa de videos muy tecnicos y sin teoria.

Comment: Te recomiendo esta página web:

https://www.sololearn.com/Play/Java

Comment: te comparto este vídeo donde se explica paso a paso como crear el primer programa en java https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5G4LvBWjX0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, Java es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, lo que significa que **TODO** debe estar dentro de una clase, incluida la clase `main` (que sería como el `int main()`en C++).

Segundo, el `args` es más avanzado, ya que sirve para llamadas especiales desde el sistema operativo (como los parámetros de `int main()` en C++).

Por último, aquí tienes el código documentado:

```
public class Braian { /*Clase del archivo. En Java, todo debe estar metido 

dentro de una clase, y solo puede haber una clase por archivo. Además, 
las clases normalmente empiezan por mayúscula, y deben llamarse como el archivo.*/
    
    public static void main(String []args){ /*Metodo principal. Static define que 
    es un método de clase, no de instancia (más avanzado). Void significa que no 
    devuelve ningún valor y public sirve para que sea accesible desde cualquier 
    parte del paquete (más avanzado). Lo de main es como el int main() de C++, y 
    String []args es para argumentos especiales para llamar desde el sistema operativo 
    (mucho más avanzado)*/
    
        System.out.println("Hola mundo"); /*Por último, esto imprime Hola Mundo. 
        System.out es una clase y println un método de esa clase (como el main). 
        Al llamarlo, imprime la cadena entre los paréntesis (como el printf(); en 
        C o el cout << en C++)*/
 }
 
}
```

Espero que te halla servido. Los novatos tenemos que ayudarnos ;)

Saludos :)

Answer (score -1):

En la programación orientada a objetos, cuando escribes una clase y esta se ejecuta, lo primero que se invocará será el método main y de hay tu puedes invocar todas las funciones adicionales que requieras.

El arreglo de argumentos, es un arreglo de tipo String, el cual se debe de pasar si o si, en ocasiones son útiles cuando construyes comandos, permitiéndote pasar parámetros o argumentos en tiempo de ejecución.